# Potential Recursive SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion

I have a three-level SQL table tree; parent, child, orphan child.

I wish to select one row from parent i.e. parent key "ID"=3

Then select all rows in table1 child where child1 key "ID1"=3 IF....

Orphan child table2 is a list of "ID2" which act as a filter for "ID1"

I have attempted a left join:

```
SELECT [itemName]
FROM [dbo].[table]
WHERE [ID] = 3
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[table1]
    ON [dbo].[table].[ID] = [dbo].[table1].[ID1]
```

The where is breaking it and I'm not even close to figuring out the 3rd level filtering of table1.

These are my table definitions.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table] (
    [ID]  INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [Company]   varchar(250)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table1] (
    [t1_fid]  INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [Product]   varchar(250),
    [Description]   varchar(250),
    [ID1] INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [dbo].[table]([ID]) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table2] (
    [t2_fid]  INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [someValue]  INT,
    [ID2] INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [dbo].[table]([t1_fid]) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

My tables are as such.

```
table:
[ID]    [Company]
1       companyA
2       companyB
3       companyC

table1:
[t1_fid]  [Product]   [Description]   [ID1]
1         Tree        Green           3
2         House       Built           1
3         Tree        Dead            3
4         Car         White           2
5         House       Sold            3
6         Car         Crashed         3
7         Car         Sold            3

table2:
[t2_fid]    [someValue]   [ID2]
1           60            1
2           2             2
3           15            5
4           0             6
```

So here is the result table I would like. It is a table of all companyC Products which also exist in table2.

```
[Company]   [Product]   [Description]   [someValue]
companyC    Tree        Green           60
companyC    House       Sold            15
companyC    Car         Crashed         0
```

I hope this enough information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pretty close. I don't see why recursion is necessary though, if I'm understanding right.

```
SELECT *
FROM table tbl
INNER JOIN table1 t1
    ON tbl.ID = t1.ID1
WHERE tbl.id = 3
  AND EXISTS
        ( SELECT 1
            FROM table2 t2
           WHERE t1.t1_fid = t2.id2
        )
```

Comment: That worked very well right out of the box! Thanks so much.

Comment: Rather than a SELECT *, is it possible to select only some of the columns from all three tables? I notice the above didn't return any data from table2. Can it be modified to that?

Answer (score 1):

Your query has a basic syntax error. This:

```
SELECT [itemName]
FROM [dbo].[table]
WHERE [ID] = 3
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[table1]
    ON [dbo].[table].[ID] = [dbo].[table1].[ID1]
```

Should be this:

```
SELECT [itemName]
FROM [dbo].[table] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[table1]
    ON [dbo].[table].[ID] = [dbo].[table1].[ID1]
WHERE [ID] = 3
```

Comment: Great thanks, now how do I add my second level filtering?

Comment: Since you only want entries from `table1` where a matching entry exists in `table2` an `INNER JOIN` between `table1` and `table2` should do what you are looking for. Include it before the `WHERE` clause but after the `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

This is very basic. You want to see data from all tables and you only want matches. This is what simple inner joins do.

```
SELECT
  t.company,
  t1.product,
  t1.description,
  t2.somevalue
FROM dbo.[table] t
JOIN dbo.table1 t1 ON t1.id1 = t.id
JOIN dbo.table2 t2 ON t2.id2 = t1.t1_fid
WHERE t.id = 3;
```

(`JOIN` is short for `INNER JOIN`.)